# How to save a matrix into a .txt file without an empty line at the end

Tags: matlab, save

I am saving a matrix into .txt file but it creates an empty line at the end, such as the example below:

```
Vele0_01 = rand(5,10);
save('name.txt','Vele0_01','-ascii');
```

How can I save it without the empty line at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Alright it seems like there is no way to do that with "save" command.

This is my solution by using "fprintf" below. Hope it helps others who needed it.

```
data = randn(10,5);
name = 'ibk.txt'
fmt=repmat('%+e  ',1,size(data,2)); % Set up format; %0.3f
fmt=[fmt(1:end-1) '\n']; % put LF at the end
fid = fopen(name, 'w');
fprintf(fid,  fmt, data(1:end-1,:).');
fprintf(fid, '%+e', data(end,:).');
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: `fprintf` works _column-wise_; in order to print the array `data` the right way, you have to `transpose` its input. the two call should be: `fprintf(fid,  fmt, data(1:end-1,:).');` and `fprintf(fid, '%f  ', data(end,:).');` (notice the `.'`.)

Comment: OMG you made my day il_raffa man, I didn't even notice it was doing that. And I was gonna waste lots of times if you didn't tell me this... I am glad I posted this question here and more glad that you replied  thanks a lot :))

Comment: il_raffa what is that "." doing to it? I know this ' is transpose.

Comment: The `'` operator performs the `conjugate transpose` while `.'` performs the `nonconjugate transpose`. While you are dealing wih matrix of only `real numbers` both the operators produce the same effect; at the contrary if you are dealing with a matrix containing `complex elements` the `'` operator by creating the `conjugate transpose` negates the sign of the imaginary part of the complex elements. You can find [more information here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html)